# EF model not being updated correctly from database

Tags: entity-framework

I have noted that one of my tables in my existing Entity Framework model has not been updated for long.
One table has news columns in the database which they are not present in the EF model.

Now I need to update de EF model to include these new columns in the table.
So from edmx designer I select the option "Update model from database..."

After doing that, new columns are added correctly to the table in EF model except one in which I am interested in. This column is a foreign key that points to another table.

So Why are some new columns added correctly to the EF model and the one I am interested in isn't?

**UPDATE**:
I am using database first. So I post here some details.

Tables in SQL Server are below:

**Table [eq].[CalibracionVerificacion]**

```
CREATE TABLE [eq].[CalibracionVerificacion](
    [calibracionVerificacionId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [equipoId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [empresaCVId] [int] NULL,
    [usuarioCVMId] [int] NULL,
    [tipo] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [fechaPrevista] [datetime] NULL,
    [magnitudId] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [frecuencia] [smallint] NULL,
    [fechaInforme] [datetime] NULL,
    [usuarioAprobadorId] [int] NULL,
    [fechaAprobacion] [datetime] NULL,
    [procedenciaInforme] [int] NULL,
    [numeroCertificado] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [temperatura] [int] NULL,
    [humedadRelativa] [int] NULL,
    [presionAtmosferica] [int] NULL,
    [incertidumbreMaxima] [decimal](7, 2) NULL,
    [correccionMedidas] [int] NULL,
    [controlRealizado] [int] NULL,
    [observacion] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [equipoComprobacionId] [int] NULL,
    [resultado] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [estado] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [fechaCalibracion] [datetime] NULL,
    [unidadFrecuencia] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Calibrac__596425FE797F8D7F] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [calibracionVerificacionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [eq].[CalibracionVerificacion]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo] FOREIGN KEY([equipoId])
REFERENCES [eq].[Equipo] ([equipoId])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [eq].[CalibracionVerificacion] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [eq].[CalibracionVerificacion]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo1] FOREIGN KEY([equipoComprobacionId])
REFERENCES [eq].[Equipo] ([equipoId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [eq].[CalibracionVerificacion] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo1]
GO
```

**Table [eq].[Equipo]**

```
CREATE TABLE [eq].[Equipo](
    [equipoId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [empresaPropietariaId] [int] NULL,
    [sociedadId] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [unidadOrganizativaId] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [delegacionPropiedadId] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [magnitudId] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [subMagnitudId] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [familiaId] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [axaptaId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [denominacion] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [equipoPropio] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [equipoPatron] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [usuarioSegundoResponsable] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [mailSegundoResponsable] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [modelo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [numeroSerie] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [capacidad] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [fechaAdquisicion] [datetime] NULL,
    [fechaFin] [datetime] NULL,
    [precioSinIva] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [observacion] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [motivoBaja] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [estado] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [equipoIdOldSocotec] [int] NULL,
    [marcaId] [smallint] NULL,
    [limitacion] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [proveedor] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [tipoId] [int] NULL,
    [usuarioResponsableId] [int] NULL,
    [activoFieldeas] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Equipo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [equipoId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Below is the generated DDL dbModel.edmx.sql. I have udpated the model from database using option "Update model from database" from model designer, but  as you can see equipoId and equipoComprobacionId fields which are foreign keys are not created in the model in table [CalibracionVerificacion]. Why?

```
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Dropping existing FOREIGN KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID(N'[eq].[FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [eq].[CalibracionVerificacion] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[eq].[FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo1]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [eq].[CalibracionVerificacion] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo1];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[st].[FK_EquipoUtilizado_Equipo]', 'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [st].[EquipoUtilizado] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_EquipoUtilizado_Equipo];
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Dropping existing tables
-- --------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID(N'[eq].[CalibracionVerificacion]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [eq].[CalibracionVerificacion];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[eq].[Equipo]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [eq].[Equipo];
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[st].[EquipoUtilizado]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [st].[EquipoUtilizado];
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all tables
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating table 'Equipo'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Equipo] (
    [equipoId] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [empresaPropietariaId] int  NULL,
    [sociedadId] varchar(4)  NOT NULL,
    [unidadOrganizativaId] varchar(10)  NOT NULL,
    [magnitudId] nvarchar(10)  NULL,
    [subMagnitudId] nvarchar(10)  NULL,
    [familiaId] nvarchar(10)  NULL,
    [axaptaId] varchar(10)  NULL,
    [denominacion] varchar(75)  NULL,
    [equipoPropio] smallint  NOT NULL,
    [equipoPatron] smallint  NOT NULL,
    [usuarioSegundoResponsable] varchar(75)  NULL,
    [mailSegundoResponsable] varchar(75)  NULL,
    [modelo] varchar(50)  NULL,
    [numeroSerie] varchar(25)  NULL,
    [capacidad] varchar(25)  NULL,
    [fechaAdquisicion] datetime  NULL,
    [fechaFin] datetime  NULL,
    [precioSinIva] decimal(10,2)  NULL,
    [observacion] varchar(500)  NULL,
    [motivoBaja] varchar(500)  NULL,
    [estado] smallint  NOT NULL,
    [equipoIdOldSocotec] int  NULL,
    [marcaId] smallint  NULL,
    [limitacion] varchar(500)  NULL,
    [proveedor] varchar(500)  NULL,
    [delegacionPropiedadId] varchar(4)  NULL,
    [tipoId] int  NULL,
    [usuarioResponsableId] int  NULL,
    [activoFieldeas] bit  NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'EquipoUtilizado'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EquipoUtilizado] (
    [equipoUtilizadoId] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [seguimientoTrabajoId] int  NOT NULL,
    [mantenimiento] bit  NULL,
    [orden] tinyint  NULL,
    [Equipo_equipoId] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'CalibracionVerificacion'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CalibracionVerificacion] (
    [calibracionVerificacionId] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [empresaCVId] int  NULL,
    [usuarioCVMId] int  NULL,
    [tipo] smallint  NOT NULL,
    [fechaPrevista] datetime  NULL,
    [magnitudId] nvarchar(10)  NULL,
    [frecuencia] smallint  NULL,
    [fechaInforme] datetime  NULL,
    [usuarioAprobadorId] int  NULL,
    [fechaAprobacion] datetime  NULL,
    [procedenciaInforme] int  NULL,
    [numeroCertificado] varchar(25)  NULL,
    [temperatura] int  NULL,
    [humedadRelativa] int  NULL,
    [presionAtmosferica] int  NULL,
    [incertidumbreMaxima] decimal(7,2)  NULL,
    [correccionMedidas] int  NULL,
    [controlRealizado] int  NULL,
    [observacion] varchar(500)  NULL,
    [resultado] smallint  NOT NULL,
    [estado] smallint  NOT NULL,
    [fechaCalibracion] datetime  NULL,
    [unidadFrecuencia] nvarchar(2)  NULL,
    [Equipo_equipoId] int  NOT NULL,
    [Equipo1_equipoId] int  NULL
);
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all PRIMARY KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating primary key on [equipoId] in table 'Equipo'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Equipo]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Equipo]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([equipoId] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [equipoUtilizadoId] in table 'EquipoUtilizado'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EquipoUtilizado]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_EquipoUtilizado]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([equipoUtilizadoId] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [calibracionVerificacionId] in table 'CalibracionVerificacion'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CalibracionVerificacion]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_CalibracionVerificacion]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([calibracionVerificacionId] ASC);
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all FOREIGN KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating foreign key on [Equipo_equipoId] in table 'EquipoUtilizado'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EquipoUtilizado]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EquipoUtilizado_Equipo]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Equipo_equipoId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Equipo]
        ([equipoId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_EquipoUtilizado_Equipo'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_EquipoUtilizado_Equipo]
ON [dbo].[EquipoUtilizado]
    ([Equipo_equipoId]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Equipo_equipoId] in table 'CalibracionVerificacion'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CalibracionVerificacion]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Equipo_equipoId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Equipo]
        ([equipoId])
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo]
ON [dbo].[CalibracionVerificacion]
    ([Equipo_equipoId]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Equipo1_equipoId] in table 'CalibracionVerificacion'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CalibracionVerificacion]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo1]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Equipo1_equipoId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Equipo]
        ([equipoId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo1'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo1]
ON [dbo].[CalibracionVerificacion]
    ([Equipo1_equipoId]);
GO
```

So as above explained, since equipoId and equipoComprobacionId fields which are foreign keys are not created in the model in table [CalibracionVerificacion], then below Linq query are not working, that is, fechaPrevista is getting Nothing because c3.equipoId and  c.equipoId  are always 0 because equipoId field is always 0 and not present in table CalibracionVerificacion. So the problem is that equipoId field in CalibracionVerificacion table is never being loaded in the model. Why?

```
Dim eq = db.Equipo
For Each equipo As Equipo In eq

            Dim fechaPrevista As DateTime? = If(Not (equipo.CalibracionVerificacion.Any()) OrElse
                                               Not (equipo.CalibracionVerificacion.Any(Function(x) Not (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.magnitudId)))),
                                                                    CType(Nothing, DateTime?),
                                                                    (From c In equipo.CalibracionVerificacion
                                                                     Join c2 In
                                                                         (From c3 In equipo.CalibracionVerificacion
                                                                          Where c3.equipoId = equipo.equipoId AndAlso Not (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c3.magnitudId))
                                                                              Group c3 By c3.magnitudId Into cgroup = Group
                                                                          Select New With
                                                                          {
                                                                              Key .MagnitudID = magnitudId,
                                                                              Key .MaxDate = cgroup.Max(Function(x) x.fechaPrevista)
                                                                          }
                                                                         ) On New With {.JoinProperty1 = c.magnitudId, .JoinProperty2 = c.fechaPrevista} Equals
                                                                              New With {.JoinProperty1 = c2.MagnitudID, .JoinProperty2 = c2.MaxDate}
                                                                     Where c.equipoId = equipo.equipoId
                                                                     Select c).Min(Function(d) d.fechaPrevista))

Next
```

**LAST ATTEMPT**:

From model designer I have deleted all the tables. Then I have gone through option "Update model from database..." and I have selected "Add" tab. Finally I select the tables above indicated which I am interested in and all three tables are inserted correctly into the model edmx, also equipoId and equipoComprobacionId  fields are added correctly into table [CalibracionVerificacion]. Relations between tables are created correctly as well. Finally I successfully build the solution and execute it. I put a breakpoint in the above LINQ expression to debug it, after pressing F10 to proceed with its execution an exception is thrown saying this:

> {"Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  The relationship
>   'MyModel.FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo' was not loaded because the
>   type 'MyModel.CalibracionVerificacion' is not available. The following
>   information may be useful in resolving the previous error: The
>   required property 'equipoComprobacionId' does not exist on the type
>   'MyService.CalibracionVerificacion'.
>
> The relationship 'MyModel.FK_CalibracionVerificacion_Equipo1' was not
>   loaded because the type 'MyModel.CalibracionVerificacion' is not
>   available. The following information may be useful in resolving the
>   previous error: The required property 'equipoComprobacionId' does not
>   exist on the type 'MyService.CalibracionVerificacion'.
>
> "}

Below are the entities generated by EF:

```
Partial Public Class Equipo
    Public Property equipoId As Integer
    Public Property empresaPropietariaId As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property sociedadId As String
    Public Property unidadOrganizativaId As String
    Public Property delegacionPropiedadId As String
    Public Property magnitudId As String
    Public Property subMagnitudId As String
    Public Property familiaId As String
    Public Property axaptaId As String
    Public Property denominacion As String
    Public Property equipoPropio As Short
    Public Property equipoPatron As Short
    Public Property usuarioSegundoResponsable As String
    Public Property mailSegundoResponsable As String
    Public Property modelo As String
    Public Property numeroSerie As String
    Public Property capacidad As String
    Public Property fechaAdquisicion As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property fechaFin As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property precioSinIva As Nullable(Of Decimal)
    Public Property observacion As String
    Public Property motivoBaja As String
    Public Property estado As Short
    Public Property equipoIdOldSocotec As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property marcaId As Nullable(Of Short)
    Public Property limitacion As String
    Public Property proveedor As String
    Public Property tipoId As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property usuarioResponsableId As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property activoFieldeas As Nullable(Of Boolean)

    Public Overridable Property CalibracionVerificacion As ICollection(Of CalibracionVerificacion) = New HashSet(Of CalibracionVerificacion)
    Public Overridable Property CalibracionVerificacion1 As ICollection(Of CalibracionVerificacion) = New HashSet(Of CalibracionVerificacion)
    Public Overridable Property EquipoUtilizado As ICollection(Of EquipoUtilizado) = New HashSet(Of EquipoUtilizado)

End Class

Partial Public Class CalibracionVerificacion
    Public Property calibracionVerificacionId As Integer
    Public Property equipoId As Integer
    Public Property empresaCVId As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property usuarioCVMId As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property tipo As Short
    Public Property fechaPrevista As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property magnitudId As String
    Public Property frecuencia As Nullable(Of Short)
    Public Property fechaInforme As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property usuarioAprobadorId As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property fechaAprobacion As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property procedenciaInforme As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property numeroCertificado As String
    Public Property temperatura As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property humedadRelativa As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property presionAtmosferica As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property incertidumbreMaxima As Nullable(Of Decimal)
    Public Property correccionMedidas As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property controlRealizado As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property observacion As String
    Public Property equipoComprobacionId As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property resultado As Short
    Public Property estado As Short
    Public Property fechaCalibracion As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property unidadFrecuencia As String

    Public Overridable Property Equipo As Equipo
    Public Overridable Property Equipo1 As Equipo

End Class
```

What's happening?

Comment: We are kinda flying blind without knowing more specific details.  Maybe update your question and add details about the two tables / fields in question?

Comment: @devlincarnate I have updated my post. The main problem is that equipoId field in table CalibracionesVerificaciones is not being created nor loaded in the model.